# Не ставится background у toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Есть *toolbar*:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

Подключаю так:

```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

   if (toolbar!=null){
       toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
   }
```

Определил цвета в color.xml

```
       <color name="colorPrimary">#FF5722</color>
       <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E64A19</color>
       <color name="colorAccent">#E64A19</color>
```

А так же style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Загружаю приложение, но цвет *toolbar*-у не задается.

Почему это происходит?

Ниже есть *tablayout* тоже без *background*-а.

Comment: А вы пробовали назначать фон тулбару ДО назначения его actionBar-ом?

Comment: Без результатно(((

Comment: а зачем вам ещё программно задавать цвет, если он прописан в разметке?

Comment: так вот это и проблема, что ни так ни так не работает((( что делать? АААА

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить строчку

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

на

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

**UPD:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundColor((new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar красным, говорит что не может найти такое!!!

Comment: getSupportActionBar - это метод активити. Если вы вызываете его не из активити, то вызывайте его из ссылки на неё.

Comment: Есть ли разница что я наследуюсь от public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: @duddeniska Вы вызывали именно метод `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: Да(( и вообще почему не работает я даже в разметке указал цвет!

Comment: @duddeniska и вызываете этот метод в `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: да(( но почему то не могу указать цвет а только Drawable

Comment: и у меня стиль без Action bar